# How to right align RadioButton in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

Trying this tutorial
http://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html

and thought of adding a radio button as follows

```
   <ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Some1}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Firstname, FallbackValue=FirstName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Lastname, FallbackValue=LastName}" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age, FallbackValue=Age}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Role, FallbackValue=Role}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" GroupName="A1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

but the resulting output is

[image]

Any help in aligning the radio button to the right next to the edge of listbox? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to [get the template content to stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the), then you can create a content which has things aligned on the right.

Answer (score 3):

You need to align the widths of the grids within your `DataTemplate`. You can do this with a `SharedSizeGroup`, see this question for details:

[How can I make a column in a listbox in WPF the same width for all items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102734/how-can-i-make-a-column-in-a-listbox-in-wpf-the-same-width-for-all-items)

Comment: This won't fix the issue, the RadioButtons will be lined up but they still won't be on the right.

Comment: @ColinE, the RadioButtons line up but they're not on the right still

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details to @ColinE answer...

Use SharedSizeGroup.

```
<ListBox ... Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
   ...
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
       <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="secondColumn" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   ...
</ListBox>
```

That will tell WPF to synchronize the second column of all the grids (technically, the width is 'Auto', but it will be the same width for all the Grids).

Another alternative would be to use ListView, and define the columns.

Comment: Not the issue here, the second column should be talking all space that is left which would make the RadioButton be on the right automtatically. The problem is that the Grid itself does not take all space.