# XAML - Collection->ListView->GridView->DataTemplate Column Fill-Width Binding issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, data-binding

I have the following View:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="CallTypePriorityMapping.MapperView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CallTypePriorityMapping.Views"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:CallTypePriorityMapping.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:CallTypeMappingsPresenter />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="MappingGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" x:Name="Col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" x:Name="Col2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="259*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="+ New Mapping" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddMapping, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Mappings, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Call Type" x:Name="callTypeCol">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="CallTypeName" ItemsSource="{Binding DBCallTypes, ElementName=userControl}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Value"  SelectedItem="{Binding CallType.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Priority">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PriorityName" ItemsSource="{Binding DBPriorities, ElementName=userControl}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Screen Capture]

This, for the most part, works, but I have a couple issues:

<strike>1. Changing either column's value on a single row also changes that value in all other rows.</strike> *Solved - See below comment from @Amine*

2. I cannot get the columns & comboboxes to auto-size (to equal portions of the fill width). The `Width` property on GridView & GridView Columns will not accept `*` (or a percentage). I've tried Binding to the outer `Grid`'s `ActualWidth`, but that grid's `ActualWidth` property always returns `0` (even after hooking into the re-size event and setting a dependency property, then re-sizing and walking the code in debug). I've been searching and reading similar posts all over the web, but see a lot of people using [Code-Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352829/listview-equal-width-for-all-columns) or [GridColumnDefinitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558795/how-can-i-make-my-grid-columns-always-be-the-same-width) (which seems to only exist in the `Grid` control, not the `GridView` control). I've also found many ways to solve this by replacing the GridView with another class, but have found no XAML-only solution using the GridView class. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can answer to your first question. The problem is in your cs code. you are puting the same collection into *DBPriorities* property for all objects of *Mappings* collection... You must create new instance for each object

Comment: You can share cs code if it's not clear

Comment: Thank you @Amine .One down. :-)

Comment: Anime - If you wouldn't mind taking a look at a followup question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018071/wpf-binding-resourcedictionary-source-to-a-resourcedictionary-property-of-the Thank you.

Comment: Try this <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>